# What to do about dependencies with GitHub

Tags: github

Reason I ask is because [they suggest](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota) not to commit dependencies on your repos.

I don't want to use a package manager like they suggest, any better suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate why a package manager is not suitable in your situation?

Comment: If personal preference counts, that's why. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git supports [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) if your dependancies are whole projects. Otherwise, package managers are the best practice.